# Why do we have $X\in \mathcal{L}^1(P(.|A))$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ be the set of integrable functions with respect to measure $\mu$.

Assuming that $X\in \mathcal{L}^1(P)$, we have $1_{A}X \in \mathcal{L}^1(P)$. But why do we have $X\in \mathcal{L}^1(P(.|A))$?

I'm using the following definition: $P(B|A)= \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$ if $P(A)>0$, and zero otherwise.

Edit:
$X\in \mathcal{L}^1(P)$ is equivalent to $\int_{\Omega} |X| dP< \infty$, so $X\in \mathcal{L}^1(P(.|A))$ is equivalent to $\int_{\Omega} |X| dP(.|A)< \infty$.

Comment: To prove or disprove $X\in \mathcal{L}^1(P(.|A))$ you must compute a certain integral.  What integral is that?  What do you get when you compute it?

Comment: @GEdgar I've added the integral. The thing is, I don't know how to translate $\int dP(.|A)$ to a $\int dP$... At least, the book I'm reading hasn't proved a theorem for that, I think. But if I were to try to prove something,  I would say that it's equal to $\frac{\int_{\Omega \cap A}|X| dP}{P(a)}$

Comment: How do you define integrals ... first can you do an indicator function?  Then can you do a simple function?  Then can you do a general measurable function?

Comment: @GEdgar I've edited my previous comment. The problem is that after this statement, the author of the book states: «Hence we can define the expectation of X w.r.t. P(.|A)», which is exactly what you're asking me. So, it would seem, at least to me, that we would be able to prove integrability, without defining/playing with that integral directly...